# Running an Ubuntu wireless access point with NTLM

Tags: networking, server, proxy, iptables

An ubuntu 18.04 server is located in our company behind a corporate proxy and should serve as an access point using a wifi usb adapter (`wlan0` interface). Authentication is done via NTLM and CNTLM is installed locally on the server and runs on port `3128`. Basically i need a forwarding from `wlan0` to `eth0` and using the local CNTLM to authenticate. Ipv4 forwarding is set and I already tried the following iptables :

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE 
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

But im still missing the entries to forward the requests to the local CNTLM proxy.

Comment: Is the server running Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes its an ubuntu server